# Mongoose save() doesn't return promise

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

Mongoose's documentations affirms that method save returns a promise. I would like to save a user model in my database using this method. I do this like that :

```
save (user) {
    user.save((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(err);
        } else {
            console.log('The user ' + user.screenName + ' has been added.');
        }

        this.db.close();
    });
}
```

Note that user param is :

```
mongoose.model('User', this.userSchema);
```

I don't understand why the console.log below returns false :

```
console.log((userRepository.save(user) instanceof Promise));
```

And of course when I try to then() the promise I doesn't work.

Am I missing something ? I also tried to return the user.save(...) but it still did not work.

Thanks for reading my message and have nice day!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, your `save(user)` method doesn't currently `return` anything itself, so the result will always be `undefined` regardless of Mongoose' behavior:

```
console.log(typeof userRepository.save(user) === 'undefined'); // true
```

However, Mongoose generally makes you choose either callbacks or promises with each of its methods. <s>The documentation isn't especially clear about this, beyond implying it through example snippets:</s> [Mongoose's documentation does now clarify this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save):

> **Returns:**
>
> - **«Promise,undefined»** Returns undefined if used with callback or a Promise otherwise.

Callback:

> ```
> product.sold = Date.now();
> product.save(function (err, product) {
>   if (err) ..
> })
> ```

Promise:

> ```
> product.save().then(function(product) {
>    ...
> });
> ```

In your case, if you want to return a `Promise`, then your `save(user)` method will also have to use and `return` them:

```
save (user) {
    return user.save()
        .then(user => console.log('The user ' + user.screenName + ' has been added.'))
        .catch(err => handleError(err))
        .finally(() => user.db.close());
}
```

(Note: [regarding `.finally()`](http://node.green/#ES2018-features-Promise-prototype-finally))

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan  Lonowski !

Comment: Hi @JonathanLonowski how would you make the example above aync ?
Would it be: 
`async save (user) {
    return await user.save()
        .then(user => console.log('The user ' + user.screenName + ' has been added.'))
        .catch(err => handleError(err))
        .finally(() => user.db.close());
}`